# Context in esper

Tags: esper

I am a novice in using the Esper event stream engine in Java.
I have two input stream one about States (device, state), and another about Measures (device, temperature)
It is possible to create a context to segment by device both streams?

Answer (score 1):

I found an example in the documentation for you. It is at [1] and "4.2.2.1. Multiple Stream Definitions".

[1] http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-5.0.0/doc/reference/en-US/html_single/index.html#context_def_keyed

Answer (score 0):

you also can create a window where you put only once the device.

for example

create window devicesDetail.std:unique(device) as (device string, temperature long, state string)

insert into devicesDetail select device, 0 as temperature, state from stream1

insert into devicesDetail select device, temperature, '' as state from stream2

and then you do a query into that window

select irstream from devicesDetail